# How to change files extension via MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file, directory, format, command

I would like to change the extension of several files.

I mean that in one directory a I have many files in type `file1.out`, `file2.out`, ..., `file600.out`.

I would like to rename these files to `*.txt` (I mean `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, ..., `file600.txt`) in this directory with one command via MATLAB?

I mean I would like to change the extension of some files from *.out to *.txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/338822-rename-files-using-matlab) can be helpful:

```
% Get all text files in the current folder
files = dir('*.out');
% Loop through each file 
for id = 1:length(files)
    % Get the file name 
    [~, f,ext] = fileparts(files(id).name);
    % change the extension
    rename = strcat(f,'.txt') ; 
    movefile(files(id).name, rename); 
end
```

Comment: Excuse me, could I do this working from different directories? I mean i would like to use a command , or to transform your solution, in order to run it for all directories?

Comment: @MichRav Of course. You can change the directory address in `dir` function like `dir('/your directory address/*.out');`